# Can't send ArrayList to other non-activity class:

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Here i am declaring the arraylist and adding value to it:

```
private ArrayList<String> act = new ArrayList<String>();
act.add("ds");
```

Here i am creating the method which is returning the arraylist:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAct() {
        return act;
}
```

Here i am getting it:

```
private ArrayList<String> act = new MainActivity().getAct();
```

And when i get the size of act is 0(it is empty). Can you tell me why?

Comment: You have to create your method as static -

Comment: Ok, but my act is not static.

Comment: Where in the class are you calling `act.add("ds");`?

Comment: You're creating a new instance of `MainActivity` and then you wonder why it doesn't share the same variable as the old instance?

Comment: declare it as astatic

Comment: Yes Tom, i am wondering that.

Comment: Huh? Never call `new MainActivity()` And I'm pretty sure that you are not setting list in `MainActivity` constructor.

Comment: @radibg2 why should two different instances of the same class share the same content of their non-static fields? The *new* instance has no relation to the *old* one, except of static fields or stuff that was passed using a constructor or a setter method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a `new` instance of any class, all non-static variables are initialized to their default values. If you really want to get the `ArrayList` in that way, either you need to use the same `Activity` reference:

```
private ArrayList<String> act = mainActivity.getAct();
```

or you need to make that variable `static`:

```
private static ArrayList<String> act = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then the following will work:

```
private ArrayList<String> act = new MainActivity().getAct();
```

Comment: You mean `MainActivity.getAct();` (instead of `new MainActivity().getAct();`)?

Comment: Never do `new MainActivity()`  One cannot create a subclass of android.app.Activity and have the result fully functional. Only the platform can do that. You create an Activity by firing an Intent, and let the platform make the constructor and necessary subsequent initialization calls.

Comment: `mainActivity` in my answer is a class instance. If he makes `act` as `public static` instead of `private static` then he can access it as `MainActivity.getAct()` i.e. without creating an instance of `MainActivity`

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I myself feel that way ... never create an `Activity` like that through a constructor. The OP will learn the hard way I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using construction `new MainActivity().getAct()` you have to fill your array in Activity constructor. So if you're doing it in lifecycle, it will will be empty.

It's better to use static factory to provide your array and pass it later to your activity.

Comment: Beyond this, one cannot instantiate a subclass of android.app.Activity and have the result fully functional.  Only the platform can do that.  You create an Activity by firing an Intent, and let the platform make the constructor and necessary subsequent initialization calls.